# How to handle dependent drop-down in Geb

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

On the selection of one drop-down multiple drop-down generated automatically as per selected value of first drop down.
The value of first drop down is between 1 to 7.
If I select 4 in parent then 4 child drop-down generate.
How to handle this problem by using geb page object and utilize it in test spec.
[Sample UI of mentioned problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J0UH.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is the question? Where is the code? Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How are the child drop-downs generated? Is there some JavaScript involved or are the children already on the page and just not displayed?

For the first option, I suggest you execute the JS script via [Geb how to deal with dynamic content](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#javascript-ajax-and-dynamic-pages).

You can pass parameters to the script (so you can pass what you select in the drop down).

In the page object that describes your page you can do something like:

```
parent{$("select", id: "parent")}
children {}
```

and add child dropdowns to `children` after. (I don't have enough details to give you a precise answer here.)

If the children are just not displayed until you select an option in the parent dropdown you can define them from the beginning in your page object. Even if you don't see them, they exist in the document your browser will interpret.

Comment: Generally it's a good idea to avoid answering questions with insufficient details for a good answer, as your answer may be downvoted or the question deleted.